# How to install a specific version of a package with pip?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, django-modeltranslation

I have set up a virtual environment on my server as well as in my local dev environment.

On the server, the package `django_modeltranslation-0.4.0_beta2` works perfectly fine. However, on my local machine, `django_modeltranslation-0.5.0-alpha` doesn't seem to work well at all.

I usually simply install it in a virtual environment like this:

```
$ source bin/active
(env)$ pip install django_modeltranslation
```

This gets the latest version though, which now for the first time causes issues working with latest version.

So I have uninstalled the version 5 alpha like this:

```
(env)$ pip uninstall django_modeltranslation
```

I tried this with no success:

```
(env)$ pip install django_modeltranslation-0.4.0_beta2
Downloading/unpacking django-modeltranslation-0.4.0-beta2
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-modeltranslation-0.4.0-beta2
No distributions at all found for django-modeltranslation-0.4.0-beta2
```

How can I get the working version 0.4.0 Beta again?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Use `==`:

```
pip install django_modeltranslation==0.4.0-beta2
```

Comment: @Kave: I realize that a recent 'just hack at it until it works' session included `#version` where it happened to work because of other reasons. Removed that variant altogether.