# how do I downgrade salt minion to an older version?

Tags: salt-stack

I need to use version 0.13.0 instead of version 0.15.x.
It seems stack overflow requires me to add 
many lines of text below this line,
when all I want to ask is a simple question
on how to down grade salt minion
can't find any ppa...
repository that has it or anything...

Answer (score 6):

More complete answer:

```
git clone git://github.com/saltstack/salt  
cd salt  
git checkout v0.13.0  
sudo python setup.py install --force
```

These are the actual commands you would use.  Note that I checked out the `v0.13.0` *tag* as opposed to the branch.  Tags are used for specific release points, branches are not guaranteed to match.  Tags are always formatted `vX.XX.X`

Comment: force installing something from git is not safe or clean in any scenario.

Comment: You're right. This is also from 2013. Since then repo.saltstack.com had been created with packages for a variety of operating systems. Using packages is usually the right choice and supports downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest this method. Since it will be really hard to maintain it, upgrading/unistalling.

In order to remove it, you will need to do it manually.

A better way is through pip and defining the specific version as is being described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916820/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-a-package-with-pip).

Comment: pip is not really a safe way to handle packages.  better than force installs from git, but still not really a safe way to deploy stuff.  It also likely violates your package managers understanding of the package.

Answer (score -1):

```
clone salt git repo

checkout 0.13 branch

sudo python setup.py install --force
```

got this from salt irc...