# pybrain install error: 'invalid command name'

Tags: python

I have downloaded `pybrain` and I want to install it. So, I create a directory Networks and inside the directory of `pybrain` I use the following command:

```
$ python setup.py install --prefix == ~/Networks/
```

And I have the following output:

```
invalid command name '/Users/petrosypsilantis/Networks/
```

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I think you're not supposed to have spaces after `prefix` and after the equals sign.

Comment: And no double equals sign. Just `python setup.py install --prefix=~/Networks/`

Answer (score 0):

You could try.

```
pip install pybrain
```

My answer is to motivate you to move away from setuptools, especially if you are having issues with it. See: [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) on how to install a specific development package using pip.

Comment: that do not address OP question about install from source. f.ex. you dev version of a package can't be installed with pip.

Comment: Agreed. But he didn't specify that he **had** to install from source. It is a bit off topic, however I firmly believe in using Pip.