# Syntax error when importing openpyxl in Qpython 3 under Android

Tags: android, tablet, openpyxl, qpython3

I installed Qpython3 and openpyxl (through pip) onto my Lenovo A3300-H tablet (Android 4.4.2). Both installations went ok, but when I tried an "import openpyxl" on the console, I got an error message apparently related to a syntax-related error in openpyxl :

---

> /data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/bin/qpython.sh && exit
>     /files/bin/qpython.sh && exit                                            <
>     Python 3.2.2 (default, Jun 18 2015, 19:03:02)
>     [GCC 4.9 20140827 (prerelease)] on linux-armv7l
>     Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import openpyxl
> > > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > > >             File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/**init**.py", line 29, in 
> > > >               from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
> > > >           File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/**init**.py", line 5, in 
> > > >               from .workbook import Workbook
> > > >             File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 8, in 
> > > >               from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet
> > > >           File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/**init**.py", line 4, in 
> > > >               from .worksheet import Worksheet
> > > >             File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 23, in 
> > > >               from openpyxl.utils import (
> > > >             File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/**init**.py", line 5, in 
> > > >               from .cell import (
> > > >             File "/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/cell.py", line 202
> > > >               sheetname = u"'{0}'".format(sheetname)
> > > >                                ^
> > > >           SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

The above text does not reflect the code exactly, so here is a Dropbox link of an image of the copy/paste : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mmqpz69vs6wy0z/ErrorMsg_import_openpyxl_in_Qpython3_Android.PNG?dl=0. Just in case.

Now, I uninstalled and re-installed both Qpython3 and openpyxl, to no avail.

Any idea ? I must add that I also tried to install numpy on the same tablet a few times, without any success (the pip install itself failed).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Alain

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.2 is not supported by openpyxl because it cannot handle the unicode literal `u""`

Comment: Thanks. So I guess I'll have to wait Qpython3 upgrade their version of Python. Probable it was the same problem that prevented me to install numpy.

Answer (score 0):

[As Charlie Clark said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38569583/4496839), the latest version of openpyxl doesn't support python 3.2. But [version 2.0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/2.0.4) does support python 3.2, so in the meantime you could use that version instead by passing the right flags to pip. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) for details.