# how to update to a specific versionh of pyserial 2.6

Tags: python, pip, pyserial

I want to update to pyserial 2.6,I normally install using pip install pyserial,is there a pip command to install to a specific version

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip

Comment: please use proper spelling and grammar

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyserial==2.6
```

or you can as well use >= and  <=

Also, try `pip help install` to get more help on pip installation options