# Downgrade Sphinx from version 1.5.2. to version 1.4.9

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The search functionality in my Sphinx doc has stopped working after upgrading to version 1.5.1. I'm using the sphinx_rtd_theme. How do I downgrade Sphinx to 1.4.9?

Comment: That strongly depends on how you upgraded.

Comment: You mean on your local machine? Uninstall current version and try with installing the desired version (e.g. with pip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Answer (score 2):

inorder to install specific version of sphinx .type in terminal :

pip install sphinx==1.4.9

Answer (score 0):

In your Terminal:
python -m pip install sphinx==1.4.9

python -m pip install sphinx==