# Unable to install pandas from pip2 from Homebrew

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew

I install python2 in my Mac from homebre with

```
brew install python2
```

And now I want to install pandas with pip2

```
pip2 install pandas
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
grpc-google-iam-v1 0.11.1 has requirement oauth2client<4.0.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
bittrex 0.1.4 has requirement requests==2.7.0, but you'll have requests 2.17.3 which is incompatible.
zipline 1.1.1 has requirement pandas<0.19,>=0.18.1, but you'll have pandas 0.23.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-speech-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-speech-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
networkx 2.0 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.90.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to downgrade the `oauth2client` package to match the dependency? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) on how to install specific versions of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can try `import pandas` in your python2.
Check if there exists something wrong with your pandas.

In my circumstance, when I install matploit, I get the similar error with you. But matploit still work as expected.

Comment: then maybe you need to downgrade your oauth2client, it seems that the oauth2client caused this error. Downgrade your oauth2client under version4.0 may help