# Const being treated as string React.JS / fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

[image]I'm trying to take the form values and pass them into an API call, but the variable `${city}` is being treated as a string. I've looked at various other examples of variable usage within a fetch call and this does seem proper. What am I doing wrong?

The function:

```
class App extends Component {
  getWeather = async (e) => {
    const api_key = '11deac5d16f942afda257188d880da59';
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

    const call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=11deac5d16f942afda257188d880da59');
    const data = await call.json();

    console.log(data);
    }
```

The Form:

```
import React from "react";

class Form extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
    <form onSubmit={this.props.getWeather}>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
        <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" />
        <button>Fetch Weather</button>   </form>
);
}
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: Instead of single quotes use backticks (escapade here) `\`My name is${name}\``. Also check if your [fetch call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) is correct

Comment: @Tico used insomnia to verify the call. Changed to backticks and worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Haha it happens, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation in ES6 should be used with backticks. ``.

In your case, change this line:

```
const call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=11deac5d16f942afda257188d880da59');
```

to

```
const call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=11deac5d16f942afda257188d880da59`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks

```
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=11deac5d16f942afda257188d880da59`
```

vs what you have:

```
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=11deac5d16f942afda257188d880da59'
```