# Installing packages with older version of Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have Python 3.7, which currently doesn't support Tensorflow.

So I installed Python 3.6.7, went to the command line and typed in `py -m pip install tensorflow`, and still got the same error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ). No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

What can I do ensure that I'm trying to install Tensorflow using Python 3.6.7?

Comment: Are you sure that `py` command links to the Python 3.6.7?

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

The solution is to invoke version 3.6 by specifying it as follows:

`py -3.6 -m pip install tensorflow`