# Unable to install particular version of tensorflow with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Unable to install tensonflow with Pip.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.2.1
    Collecting tensorflow==1.2.1
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.1 (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.2.1
```

Comment: What is your python version and what is your operating system ?

Comment: try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812968/454827

Comment: Are you using Anaconda ? You could read a guide like [this](https://medium.com/intel-student-ambassadors/installing-tensorflow-on-windows-with-anaconda-af6fa6280a4b)..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`pip install --user install tensorflow==1.2.1.`

You might need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` if using python 3.