# Why does MATLAB produce an error when calling a python script with "from tensorflow import keras"?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have the following python script (test_from_import.py)

```
from tensorflow import keras
#import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
```

that I call from MATLAB (R2018a) with the following code:

```matlab
testDir = '.....' % Directory of 'test_from_import.py'
addpath(testDir)

% Specify Python Executable Directory.
pcPythonExeDir = 'C:\Users\dmattioli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe';
[ver, exec, loaded] = pyversion(pcPythonExeDir);
pyversion % Print to command line.

% Ensure python-matlab integration code is on matlab path.
pyDir = fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'matlab', 'external', 'interfaces', 'python');
addpath(pyDir);

% Directory containing all relevant python libraries.
pyLibraryDir = 'C:\Users\dmattioli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages';

% Add folders to python system path.
insert(py.sys.path, int64(0), testDir);
insert(py.sys.path, int64(0), pyDir);
insert(py.sys.path, int64(0), pyLibraryDir);

%% Call python script.
py_test_mod = py.importlib.import_module('test_from_import')

% % Using system call instead of matlab-python integration functionality.
% [result, status] = python('test_from_import.py') % Does not return error.
```

This produces an error message (see bottom of post) tracing back to the "from tensorflow import keras" line at the top.

This error does not occur if/when you:

1. Comment out the first line and uncomment the "import tensorflow.keras" line (the error then shifts to the "from tensorflow.keras import backend as K" line).
2. Run the command "python test_from_import.py" in the command line, or
3. Run the "[result, status] = ..." system call line instead of the "py_test_mod = ..." line (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153867-running-python-script-in-matlab), or

For various reasons, I'd prefer to resolve this problem rather than using one of those 3 alternatives.

I installed everything using pip, with tensorflow being the first installation. Versions of software (Windows 10) are:

1. Python 3.6.8 (3.7.3 has the same issue).
2. h5py 2.90
3. Keras 2.2.4
4. Tensorflow 1.14.0

```
>> py_test_mod = py.importlib.import_module('test_from_import')
Error using h5r>init h5py.h5r (line 145)
Python Error: AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5r.Reference' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
Error in h5r>init h5py._conv (line 21)
Error in __init__><module> (line 36)
from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Error in saving><module> (line 38)
  import h5py
Error in network><module> (line 40)
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import saving
Error in training><module> (line 42)
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.network import Network
Error in multi_gpu_utils><module> (line 22)
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
Error in __init__><module> (line 38)
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
Error in advanced_activations><module> (line 27)
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
Error in __init__><module> (line 29)
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
Error in __init__><module> (line 26)
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
Error in __init__><module> (line 25)
from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
Error in __init__><module> (line 82)
from tensorflow.python import keras
Error in __init__><module> (line 24)
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
Error in test_from_import><module> (line 1)
from tensorflow import keras
Error in <frozen importlib>_call_with_frames_removed (line 219)
Error in <frozen importlib>exec_module (line 728)
Error in <frozen importlib>_load_unlocked (line 677)
Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load_unlocked (line 967)
Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load (line 983)
Error in <frozen importlib>_gcd_import (line 1006)
Error in __init__>import_module (line 127)
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1151) in the `h5py` repository, the problem is some version incompatibility. The solution that worked for several people was downgrading to `h5py` v2.8.0.

Installing a specific version using `pip` can be done on Windows using:

```
pip install h5py==2.8.0 --force-reinstall
```

Some additional information about using `pip` in this context can be found in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5226311/3372061).

Comment: Yes, this does remove the '__reduce_cython__' error, however, this causes MATLAB to crash ( have tried it on two separate PCs).

Could you confirm what the versions of TensorFlow, Keras, and Numpy that should be used? I don't see that information in the link.