# Can I update TensorFlow in Anaconda?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I have Anaconda under Windows 8.1, Python 3.7 e TensorFlow 1.14. I tried some pip commands but the 1.14 is the only version installed of TensorFlow.
There are other ways to update, for example, version 1.5 ?

Thank a lot for any help!

Comment: What did you try? What happened when you did? Do you really mean "version 1.5"? i.e., you want to downgrade TensorFlow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow 1.14 is the latest release for the time being. If you wanna install a specific version

```sh
conda install tensorflow=1.5.0
```

The problem is that tensorflow 1.5 is not compatible with Python 3.7 before 1.13.0rc1.

If you need version `1.5.0`, you need to create a virtual environment with Python 3.6 using `conda`.

```sh
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
conda install tensorflow=1.5.0

# you can also install tensorflow using pip
# choose the package manager you want
conda install tensorflow==1.5.0
```

**Note**: Don't use `pip` and `conda` to install pkg at the same time in one environment. Check [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) for more info.

Comment: Hello Simba, Unfortunately I got this answer: https://scontent.fgyn2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/71142170_3566515850032615_3695485604889362432_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_oc=AQk6xaAmW_dHkyemHRYKXp678nwlMqScWe7gMwRm0BiuczfWaS6wPKfYly3N6zEzvMgEq18M8ofrLBWc3Q5r-edH&_nc_ht=scontent.fgyn2-1.fna&oh=a0cd6468ce43a8528b1d21ce5629dcf8&oe=5E3737E9

Comment: @FernandoSchimidt Sorry, I didn't notice that tensorflow 1.5.0 is not compatible with python 3.7. I've updated my answer about the problem.

Comment: Hello Simba, Can I get problemns with a virtual environment with Python 3.6 and the installed Python 3.7 at the same computer? Thank you for your help!