# Control which python version `sudo apt-get install` installs a package in

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, apt-get, rdkit

I have Python2.7, Python3.6 and Python3.7 on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. I want to install `rdkit` in Python3.6 using `apt-get install`.

The command to do that is:

`sudo apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data`

1. How do I know which python version this is getting installed in? (Without opening all my Pythons and checking)
2. How do I control which version this gets installed in?

This is a general question for packages that do not seem to be available via `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

run `pip freeze` to know which package is intalled
read more here [pip freeze doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)

and to install specific version see more here 
[Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

BTW: consider pip is the best practice : https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages