# Accessing Python V2 packages on Pypi after Python V2 EOL

Tags: python-2.7, pypi

I'm trying to install a Python v2 package (yes, EOL, I know) and when when I do a `pip install bezier`) I get a message that hints that the other side is in Python V3:

```
>> pip2 install --user bezier
Collecting bezier
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/0c/b1982f93c36fc06850a3880bb693bf24a047946633ca7403664836b9da9e/bezier-2020.5.19.tar.gz (313kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 317kB 2.4MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-qgjAbR/bezier/setup.py", line 93
        print(NUMPY_MESSAGE, file=sys.stderr)
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-qgjAbR/bezier/
```

Is there a way to access the V2 packages (secret `pip` options or manual download+install)?

This would be for Ubuntu 19.04 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5226311/3001761?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version supporting Python 2.7 is [0.9](https://pypi.org/project/bezier/0.9.0/). So

```
pip install -U "bezier==0.9.0"
```

or

```
pip install -U "bezier<0.10.0"
```

Comment: Ah, OK. Until recently I would just use `pip install` or `pip3 install` depending on target Python version and I would get the right package, so I wonder why this stopped working.

Comment: It depends on the package. Some packages declare `requires_python` version but this one doesn't.

Comment: Makes sense. Thx.