# install older version of Matplotlib in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, installation

i have a matplotlib 3.2.1 library installed in python. I want to install an older version(3.1.0).
What is the syntax i should use in anaconda prompt?

using below syntax installs the latest version, what should i try instead?

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:
`pip install matplotlib==3.1.0`