# How to instruct python pip to use a user-modified version of a package to satisfy the dependencies for other packages?

Tags: python, scipy, pip

Present version of the package scipy-1.4.1 has a compilation bug (on Cygwin) https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11319 that is very easy to fix, which I did.  I then recreated the scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz file with the bug fixed on my local machine and ran pip3.7 install /repackaged/on/my/local/machine/scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz.  After that I could load scipy from python3.7 with no problems.  However when I run pip3.7 install scikit-learn it keeps trying to download and reinstall scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz file from the original repository to satisfy the dependency of scikit-learn on scipy, even though a working up-to-date version of scipy has been installed.  Is there a way to tell pip to use your version of the package to satisfy the dependency for another package?

Comment: this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Comment: The question is how to instruct pip to use a package that was modified by a user to satisfy the dependencies, not how to install a different version of a package from the repository.

Comment: If scikit-learn's only dependency is scipy, you could always pass `--no-deps` when installing it, so it just installs that package, and doesn't try to do anything with the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I tried "pip3.7 install scikit-learn --no-deps" but it still kept trying to install the original scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz  from the repository for some reason.  I ended up just downloading the .tar.gz of the scikit-learn package and running pip3.7 on the downloaded file, and it worked. I think it'd be a nice functionality to have, for pip, where a user could just choose what packages should be used (on a local machine) for satisfying certain dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading  scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz,  fixing the compilation bug https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11319 and then installing scipy-1.4.1 by running `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`,
the two approaches that get scikit-learn installed without trying to rebuild scipy-1.4.1 from the repository are

1. Either using '--no-build-isolation' in pip install: `pip install scikit-learn --no-build-isolation` .
2. or downloading  scikit-learn-0.23.1.tar.gz and building and installing using `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` .

These solutions assume that all other packages on which scikit-learn depends have been installed.