# Dependency file in python

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful

I am new in python. I am creating an API in python using flask-restful. I have created APIs in java.In java we have pom.xml file for dependencies...is there any for python and flask-restful

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In python We generally make requirements.txt so anyone who wants to download all the requirements can simply run the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

so if you are using virtualenv you can simply do

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Otherwise you need to add all the dependencies manually & the requirements.txt file will looks like

```
decorator==4.3.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
entrypoints==0.2.3
Flask==1.0.2
google==2.0.1
```

Note: It's just for example.

Comment: for every dependency, I want to use, I have to write it down in this file .......but in a specific way right ???? where can I find that way ???

Comment: I have already given the example. like you are using the Flask package & version 1.0.2 so it will be like Flask==1.0.2. Likewise, you need to add other packages one below other.

Comment: @creatorworld `==` means "exactly this version", `>=` means "at least this version" and just the dependency itself means "doesn't matter." You can even specify a range. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `pipenv`.

In Java, you need to know where your library dependencies are located and they usually are downloaded once for each project as you need them. In other words, each project will have their own set of plugins. This is also the same for non-global NPM packages (`package.json`), Ruby gems (`Gemfile`), and so on.

But in Python, everything you install with `pip` is global. Anything you install with pip will make your system Python installation messy at best and at worst will not be portable between developer machines. We get around this problem with the concept of a *virtual environment* which more or less is a copy of whatever Python version you're using self-contained to a project.

`pipenv` works pretty similarly to `npm`.

You initialise with `pipenv --three` and use `pipenv install Flask` (for example) to install packages and keep track of them in `Pipfile.toml` and a lock file. You can then clone it on another computer and `pipfile install` to install all dependencies.

If this tool does not work for you, you may also want to try `pyenv` and `virtualenv` and use a `requirements.txt` file as suggested by Rahul.

Hope that helps!