# Installing previous version of tensorlfow on windows using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

How do I install a specific version of tensorflow on windows ?(I'm using pip 20.1.1 and python 3.8)

I've tried the command

`pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`

I get the following error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow==1.14.0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for tensorflow==1.14.0

I've also tried using to install it by downloading the .whl file by running the command

`pip install C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Here I get this error

> ERROR: tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported
> wheel on this platform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by downloading the wheel file, but you need to use python 3.7. `cp37` in the wheel filename indicates that it was built for CPython 3.7.

Once you have python 3.7, you can also `pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`. You can see the list of available wheels at https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.14.0/#files

Comment: Thank you. But how do I downgrade the python version from 3.8 to 3.7 in my virtual env ? Is there a command for it ?

Comment: You can create a new virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

So far, Tensorflow isn't supported for Python v3.8

To make use of tensorflow, you need to download previous versions of python.

About the wheel file you downloaded a file for v3.7 and trying to install with v3.8 which is why you get  `is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

**EDIT:**

Python 3.8 supports Tensorflow `v2` but not `v1`.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0+ supports Python v3.8, but Tensorflow 1 not.