# How to install websocket 8.1 via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Trying to install websocket 8.1 version but i couldnt install that spesific version.

```
pip install websockets
```

This is installing 8.0.2

> Successfully installed websockets-8.0.2

Then Im writing

```
pip install websocket 8.1
```

then it says

```
    Collecting websocket
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/6d/a60d620ea575c885510c574909d2e3ed62129b121fa2df00ca1c81024c87/websocket-0.2.1.tar.gz (195kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 819kB/s
Collecting 8.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 8.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for 8.1
```

Python and pip versions.

```
Python 3.6.0

pip 9.0.1
```

Any help apreciated...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Comment: `pip install websocket==8.1`

Comment: @piertoni  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement websocket==8.1 (from versions: 0.2.1)
No matching distribution found for websocket==8.1

Comment: @Lomtrur unfortunatelly doesnt work

Comment: I was pointing out the grammar of pip (using `=='). If it is not found maybe is not available for your platform (what are you using? Windows? I am using linux and I can install it with pip). Also availability depends on your python version.

Comment: yeah i used == , Windows 10 @piertoni

Comment: Ah, simple! You did a typo, pay attention: you have to use `websockets`, not `websocket`

Comment: There is an older package on PyPI called "websocket".  You want "websockets", and the syntax is `<package-name>==<version>` not `<package-name> <version>`.

Comment: @Iguananaut I tried that too, but it says **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement websockets==8.1 (from versions: 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 4.0, 4.0.1, 5.0, 5.0.1, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for websockets==8.1**

Comment: But there is 8.1 on windows https://pypi.org/project/websockets/#files @piertoni

Comment: What OS?  What Python version? What does `pip debug` output?

Comment: Try downloading manually and install it providing the path to the file, like: `pip install websockets-8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: i guess needs > python 3.6.1 , thanks for effort @piertoni , if you write that i can accept as answer

Comment: You guess or it works? Did you try? :)

Comment: I guessed first and tried now, it works :) @piertoni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `websocket` with `websockets`:

```
pip install websockets==8.1

Collecting websockets==8.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/cb/c35513c4a0ff24ca13e33f7336ba8c1a864449fad9fea8e37abdad11c38d/websockets-8.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (73kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 934kB/s 
Installing collected packages: websockets
Successfully installed websockets-8.1
```

I checked and it works fine.

Comment: pip install websockets==8.1                                                                                                              ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement websockets==8.1 (from versions: 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 4.0, 4.0.1, 5.0, 5.0.1, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for websockets==8.1

Comment: what is your OS ?

Comment: Why you need such specific version? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: @piertoni yeah https://pypi.org/project/crypto-com-client/#files for this project, needs 8.1

Comment: @SacmaŞeyler Ubuntu. But I think you need try `pip3 install websockets==8.1`

Comment: @SacmaŞeyler Also I think you need update python version`websockets requires Python ≥ 3.6.1`

Answer (score 1):

You need at least `python==3.6.1` in your case.