# Need a downgrade of Django on MacOS

Tags: django, macos, terminal

I'm currently using Django version-3.1.5 but for my university course it's recommended for testing version-2.2.17. Was wondering how to downgrade using MacOS Terminal? When I use `pip3 install Django-2.2.17` I get a error message saying I'm already on a newer version of Django.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install using the command

```
pip3 install django==2.2.17
```

This will install the version you have specified.