# Error installing requests module through command line

Tags: python-requests, aiohttp

I tried installing the requests module for the mu editor through command line with the following command:

```
pip install requests --target "C:\Users\Amit Singh\AppData\Local\python\mu\site-packages"
```

and it it giving me the following error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
aiohttp 3.6.2 requires chardet<4.0,>=2.0, but you have chardet 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

I tried searching about this error but to no avail. Is this error fatal in any sense? And what should I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be having conflict with your current packages preventing an install, try running:

```
pip uninstall chardet
```

to remove chardet I'm not sure why it seems to be causing your error but for some reason 4.0 appears to conflict with aiohttp if it is neccicary try installing a past version:

```
pip install chardet==2.0
```

Untested so this may not correctly run the install but could help with your issue, first try with out this packadge then try with an older version.

Installing past versions -
[Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

```
aiohttp 3.6.2 requires chardet<4.0,>=2.0
```

This is the line in your errors that makes me think this is your issue, sorry if it doesn't work