# How to install a particular version of click?

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I obtained the following error during an installation.

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
gitsome 0.8.4 requires click<7.0,>=5.1, but you have click 8.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

I tried:

```
pip install click<7.0,>=5.1
```

which led to

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
flask 2.0.1 requires click>=7.1.2, but you have click 6.7 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) should answer your question

Comment: I tried pip install click<7.0,>=5.1 and I obtained another problem with dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different errors -there ,and a version conflict you will have to resolve. gitsome needs an old click, and flask needs a new click. The only way out is to findout what package has gitsome as dependency and try to update that one - or just update gitsome, to a version that accepts a newer "click".

Comment: just try `pip install -U gitsome` - it will uppgrade gitsome there without touching the projects that depend on it. then try updating click again.

Comment: I run pip3 install -U gitsome, since using only pip gave an error about dependencies again. Then I run pip3 and that link and gave the error from my question again.

Comment: if you have to use that tarball for phoebe2 and can't update that, then, maybe ou should downgrade flask.

If you can install phoebe from source, instead of the zip file you linked before, you coul just twak the versions for click in the dependencies - or install gitsome manually and tweak the versions there - or if you are just misssng click for your setup to work, just forc the newer one - even with pip complianing about the error.

Comment: How to downgrade flask, please? I tried `pip3 install flask<2.0.1`

Comment: sorry- downgrading flask is probably the worst option there. 
just try installing a newer click. and be done with it - it won't even break things, "gitsome" just limited the version for conservadorism, and you are likely not using gitsome from the command line anyway in a web project.

Comment: I have the newest click - 8.0.1 and gitsome requires a lower version.

Comment: that is it - now forget about pip messages and just run your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233458/discussion-between-elena-greg-and-jsbueno).

Comment: What do you mean by 'run the project', please? I have a test script that does not work.