# 'pip install' ignores the provided version and tries to install the latest nevertheless

Tags: python, pip, version, package-managers

As you can see in the below code example, I want to install `watchdog==1.0.1` and yet pip always tries to install the latest version (see [watchdog version history](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/#history)).

```
PS C:\Users\username\Projects> pip install watchdog==1.0.1 --no-cache-dir
Collecting watchdog
  Downloading watchdog-2.1.3-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (75 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 75 kB 655 kB/s
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 1.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 1.0.1
```

Previously, I had the issue that I would always use the cached version of watchdog. The resolution was `pip cache purge` which cleans up the entire pip cache. Moreover, adding `--no-cache-dir` after the install-command should do the trick as well.
Nevertheless, `pip install` seems to consistently ignore the version provided by the user and tries to install the latest version.

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) helps?

Comment: Indeed this could be the cause of the problem, thanks for the tip. I'll include it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

A **workaround** would be:

Go to the [release files of watchdog on pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/1.0.1/#files), download it and run

```
pip install .\watchdog-1.0.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
```

This manual install works. Before, you should uninstall watchdog, in case you haven't, via `pip uninstall watchdog`.

In case there is a better solution to the initial problem of pip ignoring the specified version, please let me know.

---

**EDIT on possible cause of the problem:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226504/12298276) (credits to @Yoav Ben Haim in the first comment of my OP) suggests that

> PyPI URL links do not work at times and throw a 404-response, and thus
> fallback URL links are re-directing infinitely due to
> sourceforge.net's recent upgrade and PyPI's stale URL