# Unable to downgrade/uninstall shap (windows)

Tags: python, windows, feature-selection, shap

I want to downgrade `shap` to version 0.34.0 from 0.39.0

```
!pip uninstall shap
```

Unable to even downgrade with the below given syntax:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Comment: You're putting whitespace between the package name, the equivalence operator (`==`), and the version you're attempting to install, and it's not clear why. This syntax isn't valid, and `pip` is interpreting this as a separate "requirement" to install. Can you link to the source upon which you're basing your implicit claim that this syntax *should* work?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to uninstall the version you have

```
pip uninstall shap
```

And then you can use

```
pip install shap==0.39.0
```