# How to downgrade PyJWT package version?

Tags: python, pip

getting below error

import jwt
return jsonify({'token': token.decode('utf-8', algorithms=["HS256"])})

AttributeError: **'str' object has no attribute 'decode'**

PyJWT --> 2.1.0 and want to downgrade to 1.7.0

Where this issue I won't see.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip) might help you to cope with python package versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `pip install PyJWT==1.7.0` in the terminal.