# Problem trying to stream geotagged tweets into PostgreSQL using Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, postgresql, twitter, jupyter-notebook, twitterapi-python

I am attempting to stream tweets in a *PostgreSQL* database with *PostGIS* extension using a Python code written in *Jupyter Notebook* with no success. I have used a lot of tutorials as reference and in the first attempts the code seemed to work and there were no mistakes. I even had printed the message that I was connected to *Twitter API*. However, no tweets were uploaded into the *PostgreSQL* database. I thought the problem could be the filters (since maybe I was using filters which had no tweets for the moment), but after some runs removing filters or using other filters I found that wasn't the problem. I think the connection to *PostgreSQL* isn't the problem neither since I tried printing the tweets directly into *Jupyter Notebook* and there was no mistake and no error.

After doing some changes basing myself into guides and checking the format of *PostgreSQL* tables, I see the code connects to the Twitter API but I get this message all the time: `'str' object is not callable`

The *PostgreSQL* table is created using the following code, with the goal that the coordinates of the tweets are stored with point geometry:

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (tweet_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, user_id VARCHAR, username TEXT, tweet TEXT, hashtags TEXT, lang TEXT, created_at TIMESTAMP, coordinates GEOMETRY);
```

The used Python code is the next one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

#Import libraries
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import json
import psycopg2
import time
from html.parser import HTMLParser

#Insert Twitter keys
ckey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
csecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
atoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
asecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

#Authorize the Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

#Call the Twitter API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Define Listener block
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
   
   def __init__(self, time_limit=300):
       self.start_time = time.time()
       self.limit = time_limit
       super(MyStreamListener, self).__init__()
   
   def on_connect(self):
       print("Connected to Twitter API.")
       
   def on_status(self, status):
       print(status.text)
       
   def on_data(self, raw_data):
       try:
           datos = json.loads(raw_data)
           #Filter only tweets with coordinates
           if datos["coordinates"] != None:
               #Obtain all the variables to store in each column
               tweet_id = datos['id_str']
               user_id = datos['user']['id']
               user_name = datos['user']['name']
               tweet = datos['text']
               hashtags = datos["entities"]["hashtags"]
               lang = datos['user']['lang']
               created_at = datos['created_at']
               coordinates = datos["coordinates"]["coordinates"]
           
               # Connect to database
               dbConnect(tweet_id, user_id, user_name, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates)
           
           if (time.time() - self.start_time) > self.limit:
               print(time.time(), self.start_time, self.limit)
               return False
       
       except Exception as e:
           print(e)
           
   def on_error(self, status_code):
       if status_code == 420:
           # Returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
           return False

def dbConnect(tweet_id, user_id, user_name, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates):
   
   #Connect to Twitter database created in PostgreSQL
   conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="datos_twitter",port=5433,user="xxxxxxx",password="xxxxxxx")
   #Create a cursor to perform database operations
   cur = conn.cursor()

   #With the cursor, insert tweets into a PostgreSQL table
   command = "INSERT INTO tweets (tweet_id, user_id, user_name, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" 
   cur.execute(command(tweet_id, user_id, user_name, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates))
   
   #Commit changes
   conn.commit()
   
   #Close cursor and the connection
   cur.close()
   conn.close()

#Streaming of tweets
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener, tweet_mode="extended")
#Filtering of tweets by spatial box and keywords
myStream.filter(locations=[-10.78,34.15, 5.95,44.04], track=['Madrid', 'madrid'])
```

Comment: in `on_data()` print the `status` to see what is in it?

Answer (score 0):

in `on_data` the argument is a raw data (string json that received from twitter api endpoint)

```
def on_data(self, raw_data):
    """This is called when raw data is received from the stream.
    This method handles sending the data to other methods based on the
    message type.

    Parameters
    ----------
    raw_data : JSON
        The raw data from the stream
    """
```

use the `on_status` like [this](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/streaming_how_to.html), in this function the argumant is [`Status`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/3b3ba2494743b894a44539247fd7e5b7839c90aa/tweepy/models.py#L325) object and you can access to its fields, like `status.text`

```
def on_status(self, status):
    """This is called when a status is received.

    Parameters
    ----------
    status : Status
        The Status received
    """
```

these function names maybe change in different version of `tweepy` , read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip?rq=1) to install specified version of python package

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code, fixing the error pointed in the comment. I have `def on_status(self, status)` based on an example which worked for me before (and that I had mistakenly replaced by myself by data in that case).

The connection is created and I receive the message for that, but then 10 seconds later I get the following error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

The complete error trace is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-249caad94bfb> in <module>
      4                         tweet_mode="extended")
      5 #Filtering by spatial box and keywords

----> 6 myStream.filter(locations=[-10.78,34.15, 5.95,44.04], track=['Covid','covid-19'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in filter(self, follow, track, is_async, locations, stall_warnings, languages, encoding, filter_level)
    472             self.body['filter_level'] = filter_level.encode(encoding)
    473         self.session.params = {'delimited': 'length'}
--> 474         self._start(is_async)
    475 
    476     def sitestream(self, follow, stall_warnings=False,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in _start(self, is_async)
    387             self._thread.start()
    388         else:
--> 389             self._run()
    390 
    391     def on_closed(self, resp):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in _run(self)
    318             # call a handler first so that the exception can be logged.
    319             self.listener.on_exception(exc_info[1])
--> 320             six.reraise(*exc_info)
    321 
    322     def _data(self, data):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in _run(self)
    287                     self.snooze_time = self.snooze_time_step
    288                     self.listener.on_connect()
--> 289                     self._read_loop(resp)
    290             except (Timeout, ssl.SSLError) as exc:
    291                 # This is still necessary, as a SSLError can actually be

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in _read_loop(self, resp)
    349             next_status_obj = buf.read_len(length)
    350             if self.running and next_status_obj:
--> 351                 self._data(next_status_obj)
    352 
    353             # # Note: keep-alive newlines might be inserted before each length value.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in _data(self, data)
    321 
    322     def _data(self, data):
--> 323         if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
    324             self.running = False
    325 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py in on_data(self, raw_data)
     52         if 'in_reply_to_status_id' in data:
     53             status = Status.parse(self.api, data)
---> 54             if self.on_status(status) is False:
     55                 return False
     56         elif 'delete' in data:

<ipython-input-12-3460245af936> in on_status(self, status)
     34         if not hasattr(status, "retweeted_status") and coordinates!= None:
     35             # Connect to database
---> 36             dbConnect(tweet_id, user_id, username, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates)
     37 
     38         if (time.time() - self.start_time) > self.limit:

<ipython-input-13-d7acfb1cce67> in dbConnect(tweet_id, user_id, username, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates)
      6 
      7     command = "INSERT INTO tweets (tweet_id, user_id, username, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
----> 8     cur.execute(command(tweet_id, user_id, username, tweet, hashtags, lang, created_at, coordinates))
      9 
     10     conn.commit()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am not sure, but it seems the error comes now from the line in which I insert the tweets into *PostgreSQL*.

I have now edited the code adding the function `def on_data(self, raw_data)` and then put `def on_status(self, status)` like it has been mentioned in the comments. I continue getting the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`