# Huggingface Transformers Conda Install issue

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, huggingface-transformers

conda by default installing transformers 2.x however pip installs 4.x by default which is what I want but via conda.

If I install by specifying the latest distribution file from conda-forge…
`conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/transformers/4.16.2/download/noarch/transformers-4.16.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2`

then it complains that environment is not consistent and list the package causing the issue which is PyTorch version 1.11.

I removed pytorch and then installed as listed above then installation go through. I then tried installing datasets…
`conda install datasets`

Now it complains that environment is inconsistent due to transformers 4.16.2 that I installed.

Not sure whats wrong and how to install pytorch, transformers and datasets together with no issue.
Do I need specific versions of these to make it work, could not find any such guideline on huggingface docs or support pages.

thanks.

Comment: Could you make a reproducing example in a new environment? We don't know what else you have installed that could be causing conflicts. And making a new environment fixes this sort of issue in many cases.

Comment: Tried in a new blank environment and first package I tried to install transformers ...

Comment: continued..  `conda install -c huggingface transformers`. This time it picked up `transformers version 4.x` and `python version 3.8x`. Now, if I first install `python 3.9.x` (which is default with miniconda) and then try to install transformer then it falls back to version 2.x. This tell me that in order to have version 4.x I need python version 3.8 or lower. This is not listed anywhere in huggingface installation page though.

Comment: That's surprising; it's built as a `noarch` package which has the consequence of typically being compatible with all versions of Python. I suspect something is pulled down incorrectly in its dependencies. The documentation only gives the instructions you've followed and makes no mention of Python 3.9 incompatibility - therefore I suggest raising this as an issue with the maintainers directly. Make sure to include details logs, etc. and whatever else they may ask for in their issue prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Just tried installing transformers in the `venv` that I will be working on as follows

```
conda install transformers
```

And it installed the version `transformers-4.18.0`.

If one wants to install specifically from the channel `huggingface`, then do the following

```
conda install -c huggingface transformers
```

---

Last case scenario, install it with `pip`, as using `pip` can potentially wreck one's installation (`pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way).

```
pip install transformers
```

Or, by specifying the version

```
pip install transformers==4.18.0
```

Or directly from the source

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

If one has `transformers` already installed and wants to install a different version than the one we currently have, one should pass `-Iv` ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226504/7109869))

```
pip install -Iv transformers==4.18.0
```

---

To check if `transformers` was properly installed, run the following

```
python -c "from transformers import pipeline; print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('we love you'))"
```

It will download a pretrained model, then print out the label and score.

---

For more information on `transformers` installation, [consult this page](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to download from `conda-forge` channel instead of `huggingface` channel, i.e.
`conda install conda-forge::transformers`