# How to specify version for AZ CLI in Azure pipelines in Yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to use a task of az cli in a cloud agent, but need to use an older version, today the version used by default in windows-2019 image is az cli v.2.37.0, but I need az cli v.2.34.1.

How can I set this version in the task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Azure CLI with the `bash` [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops#hosted-agent-azure-cli-version).

```yaml
# Specify python version
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    architecture: 'x64'

# Update to latest Azure CLI version
- bash: pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
  displayName: 'Upgrade Azure CLI'
```

You can also specify a version for [pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip).

```yaml
- bash: pip install -Iv azure-cli==2.34.1 --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
  displayName: 'Upgrade Azure CLI'
```

Comment: Then can I continue with the task AzureCLI@2 with the specified version? or I need to keep in bash (or powershell)

Comment: Afterwards you can continue with other *tasks* using the installed version of Azure CLI

Comment: It worked for me ! thank you so much , it seems that it takes the latest version of az cli again when changing the stages, what about changing job? it still using the specified version?

Comment: I'm not sure. I never tested it