# How to install a specific version of python package

Tags: pip

Goal install older package:

- pypdf2==1.26.0
- reportlab==3.3.0

Is it possible to install these on MacOS BigSur with the terminal command: `pip3`?  The [pip syntax](https://www.marsja.se/pip-install-specific-version-of-python-package/) is:

```
pip install <PACKAGE>==<VERSION>
```

Is there a simple test to determine if said version of the packages are compatible with my version of python3?

I have the latest version of the packages installed and now wonder if two versions can coexist and play nicely.

Comment: You need to use virtual environments to support multiple versions of packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package version with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip)