# AttributeError: module 'dill._dill' has no attribute 'stack'

Tags: nlp, dill

Use this colab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12LjJazBl7Gam0XBPy_y0CTOJZeZ34c2v?usp=sharing

my CUDA Version: 11.2

when do this

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    process_data_to_model_inputs,
    batched=True,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    remove_columns=["article", "abstract", "section_names"],
)
```

> **AttributeError: module 'dill._dill' has no attribute 'stack'**

I have try this

```
pip install dill==0.3.4
```

but not work

How to solve this problems, Thinks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm the `dill` author. `dill._dill.stack` is not part of the public interface, and can't be guaranteed to be there. It was removed in `0.3.5` (and above). It is available in `0.3.4`.  If you have already installed `0.3.5.1` or something larger than `0.3.4`, you will need to `pip uninstall` or `force-reinstall` the specific package version.

See: [Installing specific package version with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip)

Comment: Thanks for response, it work on other platform!

Comment: I tried installing dill of version `0.3.4` and I still encounter the same error `AttributeError: module 'dill._dill' has no attribute 'stack'`

Any fix?

Comment: If you have version `0.3.4` installed, then `dill._dill.stack` exists. If you are using that version, and are seeing an attribute error for `stack`, then either you have a path issue with a different version or there'd have to be an import issue where you'd need to add an import to `__init__.py` to make the attribute available by default.