# Cannot install opencv-python and numpy with specified versions with poetry

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-poetry

I'm trying to install opencv-python 4.5.5.62 and numpy 1.19.5 with poetry, but poetry doesn't allow it. After adding opencv-python to poetry project, poetry returns error when adding numpy:

```
$ poetry add numpy==1.19.5

Because example depends on opencv-python (4.5.5.62) which depends on numpy (>=1.21.2), numpy is required.
So, because example depends on numpy (1.19.5), version solving failed.
```

While using linux and Python 3.9.7 like me, numpy 1.19.5 should be allowed to install alongside with opencv-python 4.5.5.62, as it's described in pypi requirements:

```
$ curl -s https://pypi.org/pypi/opencv-python/4.5.5.62/json | jq '.info.requires_dist'
[
  "numpy (>=1.13.3) ; python_version < \"3.7\"",
  "numpy (>=1.21.2) ; python_version >= \"3.10\"",
  "numpy (>=1.21.2) ; python_version >= \"3.6\" and platform_system == \"Darwin\" and platform_machine == \"arm64\"",
  "numpy (>=1.19.3) ; python_version >= \"3.6\" and platform_system == \"Linux\" and platform_machine == \"aarch64\"",
  "numpy (>=1.14.5) ; python_version >= \"3.7\"",
  "numpy (>=1.17.3) ; python_version >= \"3.8\"",
  "numpy (>=1.19.3) ; python_version >= \"3.9\""
]
```

It is possible to install mentioned versions with `pip`. Pip's logs show that actual numpy requirement for opencv is lower that poetry's:

```
$ pip3 install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.6.0.66-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl (46.4 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.17.3
  Using cached numpy-1.23.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (18.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python
Successfully installed numpy-1.23.2 opencv-python-4.6.0.66
```

The same problem is on ubuntu 18.04 and macOS 12.4 (Intel) with Python versions 3.8.10, 3.9.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip ?

Comment: No, because I want to use poetry for my project.