# I am using Google Colab and I updated pandas_datareader to 0.10.0, but when I check its version it shows 0.9.0

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pandas-datareader

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: pandas-datareader in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas-datareader) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas-datareader) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas-datareader) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (2022.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (3.0.4)
```

```
pandas_datareader.__version__
0.9.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package version with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip)

Comment: Or force reinstall with `!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas-datareader`.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas_datareader
```

Once you are done with the above command

Click on Runtime

Select Restart runtime

Now to check version:

```
import pandas_datareader as pr

pr.__version__
```