# AttributeError: 'TokenClassifierOutput' object has no attribute 'backward'

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I'm fine-tuning the BERT model in Named Entity Recognition task using json file dataset, but when I run that code always get an error:

```
    loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None,
                 attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
    # backward pass
    loss.backward()
```

I think the library has been changed but I don't know where can I find 'backward' attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`TokenClassifierOutput`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.TokenClassifierOutput) class contains an attribute called `loss`, which has the type `torch.FloatTensor`, from which [`.backward()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.backward.html#torch.Tensor.backward) can be called.

```py
token_classifier_output = model(b_input_ids,
                                token_type_ids=None,
                                attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                                labels=b_labels)
token_classifier_output.loss.backward()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it work with me, But after I fix this error I got another one with optimizer.step(). The error is: 
AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'step'

Comment: To avoid extended discussion in the comments section, open a new question for your new problem(s) if needed. That aside, you seem to be running some legacy code (that was written for an older version of the `transformers` package) with a newer version of `transformers` installed, which requires you to rewrite some parts of the code. If running the code with the latest version of `transformers` is *not* required, a quicker way to fix it is to **1)** find out the version of `transformers` used before, and **2)** [install that specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5226311/12122460) of it.