# how to update torch version?

Tags: python, pytorch

My project was originally able to run successfully, but it suddenly stopped running today and reported an error with the wrong version:

RuntimeError: Expected PyTorch version 1.4 but found version 2.0.

I am trying to change the torch version

Comment: after update the version,there are many other error,such as " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.profiler' "

Answer (score 0):

You can try `conda install -c pytorch pytorch=1.4` to downgrade the PyTorch version from the command line. You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip) for managing package versions with *pip*.