# Installing fairseq on my jetson nano fails

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-20.04, nvidia-jetson-nano, fairseq

[image: screen shot of the terminal]

Can fairseq be installed? If not are there any alternative to this?

Commands I ran so far:

```bash
pip install fairseq
sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev python3.8-dev
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
jetson@nano:~$ pip install cython

Requirement already satisfied: cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.29.21)
jetson@nano:~$ 
jetson@nano:~$ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 415 kB/s 
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
Successfully installed pip-24.0 setuptools-69.0.3
jetson@nano:~$ 
jetson@nano:~$ pip install fairseq
/usr/bin/pip:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
Collecting fairseq
  Using cached fairseq-0.12.2.tar.gz (9.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -4:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpfe_z5std get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp_fqxc6e7
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_yoea2wq/fairseq
  Complete output (0 lines):
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -4: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpfe_z5std get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp_fqxc6e7 Check the logs for full command output.

jetson@nano:~$ sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libblas-dev is already the newest version (3.9.0-1build1).
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.3-4).
liblapack-dev is already the newest version (3.9.0-1build1).
libopenblas-dev is already the newest version (0.3.8+ds-1ubuntu0.20.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 libxmlb1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific package version with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip)